# Cannot use library on another thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, methods

I am creating a simple application that is zipping files that the user selects. I am coding it in C++ and I use the [Zipper](https://github.com/sebastiandev/zipper) library to zip the files. Everything works great when I use the library on the same thread as the UI, but it throws this exception if I am running it from another thread:

> Unhandled exception at 0x75D33EF2 in Backup.exe: Microsoft C++
>   exception: std::exception at memory location 0x076FF6A8.

My code to create the thread is:

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, ZipFiles, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

And the code inside the method is:

```
Zipper zipper("zipfile.zip");
zipper.add("somefile.txt");
zipper.close();
```

The exception is being thrown in the first line. My problem here is honestly, the interpretation. Am I doing something wrong in the code, or is there a posibility that this library cannot be used by another thread ?

Comment: Where does exception come from (what is the call stack)? What does exception message say?

Comment: you have src code. step into [`Zipper zipper("zipfile.zip")`](https://github.com/sebastiandev/zipper/blob/master/zipper/zipper.cpp#L201). look like [here](https://github.com/sebastiandev/zipper/blob/master/zipper/zipper.cpp#L24) fail

Comment: You should be able to write a 10 line [mcve] console application that demonstrates this problem or ... does not.  Either is useful; if it demonstrates, you can get better help.  If it does not, the problem is possibly in tge *difference* between your programs.

Comment: The debugger is telling you that a `std::exception` is being thrown.  Have you tried `catch`'ing it to see what it says?

Comment: Any chance you exit the program before that thread has an opportunity to finish its job? Or, maybe, your thread is accessing some object that (by the time the thread gets to use it) goes out of scope in the "main thread" and gets destroyed?

Comment: Thank you all for your replies! I used the source code to try to debug the library as @RbMm first mentioned. It seems that zipOpen64 method failed and returned NULL for some reason, but before I finding any solution, the library started to work. Maybe it was a VS issue ? Or a library issue that does not appear all the time ? I do not know. If I encounter this error again in the future, I will update the topic.